# OOM error while fine-tuning pretrained bert

Tags: pytorch, out-of-memory, bert-language-model

I am fine-tuning **BertForPreTraining** model which has **mlm** and **nsp** heads on top of it. When I run my code it hits me with a out of memory error the moment It starts to assign the first batch to the gpu. I even tried smaller batches and it didn't work. My gpu has **2Gb** Ram and I even tried my code on a gpu with **4Gb** ram and still getting the same error. I'm coding with pytorch and cuda 11.3 . here is my code:

```
current_loc = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForPreTraining.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

with open("%s\clean.txt" % (current_loc), 'r') as fp:
    text = fp.read().split('\n')


bag = [item for sentence in text for item in sentence.split('.') if item != '']
bag_size = len(bag)

sentence_a = []
sentence_b = []
label = []

for paragraph in text:
    sentences = [
        sentence for sentence in paragraph.split('.') if sentence != ''
    ]
    num_sentences = len(sentences)
    if num_sentences > 1:
        start = random.randint(0, num_sentences-2)
        # 50/50 whether is IsNextSentence or NotNextSentence
        if random.random() >= 0.5:
            # this is IsNextSentence
            sentence_a.append(sentences[start])
            sentence_b.append(sentences[start+1])
            label.append(0)
        else:
            index = random.randint(0, bag_size-1)
            # this is NotNextSentence
            sentence_a.append(sentences[start])
            sentence_b.append(bag[index])
            label.append(1)


inputs = tokenizer(sentence_a, sentence_b, return_tensors='pt',
                   max_length=512, truncation=True, padding='max_length')

inputs['next_sentence_label'] = torch.LongTensor([label]).T
inputs['labels'] = inputs.input_ids.detach().clone()

# create random array of floats with equal dimensions to input_ids tensor
rand = torch.rand(inputs.input_ids.shape)
# create mask array
mask_arr = (rand < 0.15) * (inputs.input_ids != 101) * \
           (inputs.input_ids != 102) * (inputs.input_ids != 0)


selection = []
for i in range(inputs.input_ids.shape[0]):
    selection.append(
        torch.flatten(mask_arr[i].nonzero()).tolist()
    )

for i in range(inputs.input_ids.shape[0]):
    inputs.input_ids[i, selection[i]] = 103


class OurDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings.input_ids)

dataset = OurDataset(inputs)
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
# and move our model over to the selected device
model.to(device)

# activate training mode
model.train()

# initialize optimizer
optim = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

# torch.cuda.empty_cache()
# torch.cuda.memory_summary(device=None, abbreviated=False)

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # setup loop with TQDM and dataloader
    loop = tqdm(loader, leave=True)
    for batch in loop:
        # initialize calculated gradients (from prev step)
        optim.zero_grad()
        # pull all tensor batches required for training
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        token_type_ids = batch['token_type_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        next_sentence_label = batch['next_sentence_label'].to(device)
        labels = batch['labels'].to(device)
        # process
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask,
                        token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
                        next_sentence_label=next_sentence_label,
                        labels=labels)
        # extract loss
        loss = outputs.loss
        # calculate loss for every parameter that needs grad update
        loss.backward()
        # update parameters
        optim.step()
        # print relevant info to progress bar
        loop.set_description(f'Epoch {epoch}')
        loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())
```

And I am getting the error below:

> Some weights of BertForPreTraining were not initialized from the model
> checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized:
> ['cls.predictions.decoder.bias'] You should probably TRAIN this model
> on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and
> inference.   0%|
> | 0/159 [00:00<?, ?it/s]test.py:75: UserWarning: To copy construct
> from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach()
> or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather  than
> torch.tensor(sourceTensor).   return {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for
> key, val in self.encodings.items()}   0%|
> | 0/159 [00:22<?, ?it/s] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "test.py", line 109, in 
> outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask,   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py",
> line 1093, in forward
> outputs = self.bert(   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py",
> line 995, in forward
> encoder_outputs = self.encoder(   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py",
> line 582, in forward
> layer_outputs = layer_module(   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py",
> line 470, in forward
> self_attention_outputs = self.attention(   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py",
> line 401, in forward
> self_outputs = self.self(   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1102, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Rastin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py",
> line 305, in forward
> attention_scores = torch.matmul(query_layer, key_layer.transpose(-1, -2)) RuntimeError: CUDA **out of memory. Tried
> to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 2.00 GiB total capacity; 1.17 GiB
> already allocated; 0 bytes free; 1.23 GiB reserved in total by
> PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting
> max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for
> Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF**

Answer (score 2):

`Bert` is a large and complex NN, so I won't be surprised if it gives you the OOM error. If you've been trying with the least batch size, and it still doesn't work, then I suggest you enable the `gradient_checkpointing` config of Bert. This feature is basically a nice idea to trade-off between memory usage and GPU utilization. You can read more [here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/fitting-larger-networks-into-memory-583e3c758ff9). I actually had the same problem with my 12GB GPUs, but I managed to handle it with the gradient_checkpointing module.

According to the [docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/performance.html?highlight=gradient_checkpointing), you can turn on the gradient checkpointing for each Transformers model in two ways:

1. calling the `gradient_checkpointing_enable()` function:

   model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()
2. simply adding the `--gradient_checkpointing` flag to the Trainer arguments.

If this does not work, then you may want to remove nsp task from your pipeline to make a model a bit simpler. If that does not work either, then maybe the best option is to upgrade the GPU hardware.